# Css image position relative ignored in Safari

Tags: html, css

I have a gallery with images, structured like this (simplified):

```
<div class="gallery">
  <figure class="gallery-item">
    <a class="gallery-item-link">
      <img />
    </a>
  </figure>
 <figure class="gallery-item">
    <a class="gallery-item-link">
      <img />
    </a>
  </figure>
</div>
```

`.gallery` is a flex-container that should fit 3 items on bigger screens.

My problem is with centrally positioning of the images within `.gallery-item-link`.

The relevant piece of css is

```
.gallery-item-link img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

The sizes and ratios of the images can be varying so I cannot rely on `padding` trick for aspect ratio.

In Chrome, this is what the gallery looks like: [image: chrome]

In Safari, and this is the problem: [image]

Here is the pen to illustrate the problem: http://codepen.io/afkatja/pen/EWEMNb

Am I forgetting / missing something?

EDIT: the problem seems to have something to do with `align-items: stretch` likely not working properly (or just ignored?) in Safari?

EDIT: I am using Safari 10.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried (among various other things) using `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` for images which producesd unpredictable results and seemed so hacky.

I eventually solved the problem by using `flexbox` for image container:

```
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
```

I updated the pen here: http://codepen.io/afkatja/pen/EWEMNb

Tested in latest Chrome, Safari (both desktop and iOS), Firefox, MS Edge & IE11.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.gallery-item-link img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%; 
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50% -50%);
}
```

Comment: I updated the pen. This suggestion does not seem to change anything.

Comment: What version of safari are you using?

Comment: It may be to do with the  transform-origin: bottom left; css rule. Comment this out or change to transform-origin: top left;

Answer (score 0):

> You've got the direction for x & y wrong. it should be translateX instead of Y. try this :

.gallery-item-link img {

```
   display: block;
   max-width: 100%;
   position: relative;
   top : 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50% -50%);
```

}

Comment: Which direction for x & y I got wrong? Check my pen, I have `translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem before. Probably coz the 'relative' image cannot get how tall 50% is when the parent element don't has a specify height like 'px'.

Here is another way to do what you want...sry i can't fixed your 'relative' problem

```
&__item__link {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration: none;
  &::after{
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:100%;
  }
  img {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    max-height: 100%;
    // position: relative;
    // @include center-all;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    @include transition;
    &:hover {
      opacity: .8;
    }
  }
```

http://codepen.io/linjiyeah/pen/XMEwpb